re-search-backwards find first Uppercase letter
I want to find the first occurrence of an uppercase letter.
I am trying to use re-search-backwards; yet it is not working as intended.
Here's an example:
(defun test ()
    (interactive)
    (re-search-backward "[:upper:]"))

When used in the following phrase (standing at the end; aka the final "r"):

hi,  my Name is peter

The cursor goes to "e". How can I make the cursor go to "N".
Using re-search-backwards preferably

The syntax is [[:upper:]].

In addition to fixing the syntax of the regexp, you also need to disable case-folding:
  (defun my/test ()
      (interactive)
      (let ((case-fold-search nil))
        (re-search-backward "[[:upper:]]")))

Check the docstring of the function C-h f re-search-backward. It tells you that the function behaves like re-search-forward except in search direction, so you also need to read the docstring of that with C-h f re-search-forward which says:

Search case-sensitivity is determined by the value of the variable
‘case-fold-search’, which see.

So do C-h v case-fold-search to find out how to deal with case-sensitive searches. The idiom above is standard and very often useful.
For the regexp syntax, read the Regexp Syntax section of the manual, or better, do C-h i g(emacs) RET i regexp in your Emacs. Learning to use Info in Emacs is very useful.

Thank you. I was missing the case fold search variable

As @NickD said in a comment, you need to use "[[:upper:]]", not "[:upper:]".

The result remains the same. It does not go backwards to the N

I cannot reproduce this: with the correct syntax (and ensuring the case-fold-search is nil), running this function takes me to the N.

What @FranBurstall said. If you don't see this then make sure you're starting with vanilla Emacs: emacs -Q (no init file). If the problem is in your init file then bisect it to find the culprit.
